# Why does a random extra letter appearing in my functions name?

Tags: c++, eclipse, inheritance, virtual, abstract

I'm trying to implement an abstract class as an interface definition, and I get a weird error when deriving a class from it, saying that my function does not override the abstract definition.

Now the weird thing comes in the error message:

```cpp
'json_object* NetworkCommunication::SendMessageA(const char*, const char*, json_object*)' marked 'override', but does not override
```

Notice the extra 'A' at the end? The one that does not appear anywhere in my actual code? If I add it to the code at every definition, the compile works fine, and I can move on to my next error.

If I copy-paste this to cppshell, it doesn't cause any issue. What causes this?

```cpp
    class NetworkCommunicationInterface
    {
    public:
        virtual json_object* SendMessage(const char* msg, const char* request, json_object* json_post) = 0;
        virtual void SetBaseUrl(const std::string& url) = 0;

        virtual ~NetworkCommunicationInterface(){}
    };

    class NetworkCommunication : public NetworkCommunicationInterface
    {
    public:
        void SetBaseUrl(const std::string& url) override;
        json_object* SendMessage(const char* msg, const char* request, json_object* json_post) override;
        const char* GetBaseUrl();

        NetworkCommunication();
        virtual ~NetworkCommunication(){}

    //Implementation
    NetworkCommunication::NetworkCommunication()
    {
        base_url = "";
    }

    json_object* NetworkCommunication::SendMessage(const char* msg, const char* request, json_object* json_post)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SendMessage` is a macro which is defined as either `SendMessageA` or `SendMessageW` based on whether `UNICODE` is defined. This is in the Windows header files; so you cannot define your own function with that name -- unless you undef `SendMessage` first, which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @LRavasz These days, you usually don't go for the `A` (Ansi) versions, but the `W` (wide/unicode) versions.

Comment: Depends whether you need Unicode support. I work on rather large projects, which use the `A` version, since I do not need to support Unicode at the level these functions are used.

Comment: @LRavasz, if it answers your question, then please mark it as an answer for future readers :)

Comment: Sure `A` _works_ but some API functions don't actually work the same in both versions. Some `W` versions have a less limitations wrt path lengths etc so in my experience, it's a slightly better/friendlier API. :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Could you give an example where they work differently? I've never come across this. Wouldn't the path lengths be limited by MAX_PATH?

Comment: @ChrisMM -- it's traditional to wait a day or two before accepting an answer. Some people don't read questions that have accepted answers, so early acceptance can mean missing out on better answers (not a comment on your answer).

Comment: @ChrisMM "_the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. [...] The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of 32,767 characters_"  - So compare the versions of one of the central WinAPI functions, `CreateFile`.